# give each picture a border on click

Tags: javascript, html, function, events, border

I want to give a picture a border. But there are multiple pictures and only the ones I click on should get a border. iI could just give every picture a single ID and write a script for each but that would be too much since there are more pictures coming. I've tried multiple things, but right now the code looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- ... -->

<div>
    <img src="Champs/Vayne.png" class="vayne">
    <img src="Champs/Nasus.png" class="nasus">
</div>
<!-- ... -->

<script>

function Border()
{
    document.querySelector(".vayne").addEventListener("click", function changeBorder
    {
        changeBorder.target.style.border = "solid";
    });
}

</script>
```

I've tried to have the background change to red instead so I guess there must be a mistake in the line with the event listener but I don't know what's wrong there.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be valid JS syntax for a function.

Comment: There are a few minor problems with your code. I think if you try understanding [this W3Schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) you will be able to get your example working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This adds a border to the image when you click on the image: we create a function that adds a border to an element, and we call it when an element gets clicked (with onclick)

```
<img src="Champs/Vayne.png" onclick="mark(this)">

function mark(el) {
    el.style.border = "1px solid blue";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8QGkq/

Comment: What about that? What does that do? How does it answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This adds a border to the image when you click on the image:
we create a function that adds a border to an element, and we call it when an element gets clicked (with onclick)

Comment: Note, also, that the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: @FrancescoManicardi Add the explanation to the answer.

Comment: edited and added the explaination to the answer, thanks for the suggestions i'm new to answering questions!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you wrapped the code that attaches the event listener to the images in a function which is never getting executed. And the syntax in your callback function is wrong, you are missing the brackets around the argument.

You will have to add an event listener for each image on the page.

You can either leave the code like it is and call the function manually:

```html
<script>

function Border()
{
    document.querySelector(".vayne").addEventListener("click", function (changeBorder)
    {
        changeBorder.target.style.border = "solid 1px";
    });
}

Border(); // call the function
</script>
```

Or just remove the function and just leave the contents:

```html
<script>
document.querySelector(".vayne").addEventListener("click", function (changeBorder)
{
    changeBorder.target.style.border = "solid 1px";
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

A much better solution using only a single event handler is given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58935370/7846567

This answer also suggest that just setting the border style won't work because the border width needs to be set to something bigger than zero too. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Can you suggest a better way since this means OP would have to have 1 click event for every image on the page. That is a lot of duplicated code.

Comment: @epascarello another one just gave the correct answer, i will include this in my example

Answer (score 2):

Use a [delegated event handler](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) and use the [target of the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to assign the border:

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  if(event.target.nodeName == "IMG"){
    //note style includes the width and color as well as the border type
    event.target.style.border = "1px solid red";
  } 
});
```

This way you do not have to worry about the number of images you add the event will fire for anything clicked on and only apply to elements that are `<img>` due to the `nodeName` check.

Of course you could use other checks like class, or some other data point to determine wither or not to apply the style.

For instance you could use a [data-* attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to decide which elements should be targeted

```
//img using a data-* attribute
//<img src="..." data-clickborder="1">

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.dataset["clickborder"] == 1) {
    event.target.style.border = "1px solid red";
  }
});
```

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.dataset["clickborder"] == "1") {
    event.target.style.border = "1px solid red";
  }
});
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90">

<img data-clickborder="1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/64">

<img data-clickborder="1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/72">

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/81">
```

Note your code, incorrect syntax not withstanding, did not provide a border size but instead just a border type. No border would have showed up even if the code selected the element correctly and applied the style.

Comment: since i will add other pictures that should not get a border onclick later on can i use something else than nodeName == "IMG" ?

Comment: Yes you can use anything you want as a test point. See the updated answer on how you could use [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) for instance

Comment: thank you for your answer. i chose another way since it seems easier to understand for a beginner and i dont want to just copy and paste stuff. also thank you for the articles.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly to neaten up your code, I would suggest using jQuery as it greatly reduces the number of lines of code required to apply functions and events to DOM elements, you can do so by adding this tag: 
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>`

Then using another script, you can add an "on click" function to each img element

```
<script>
$("img").each(function() {
$(this).on("click", function() {
$(this).css("border", "1px solid black")
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you include something as big as jQuery just to reduce a few lines of code? jQuery adds much more overhead as needed

Comment: I'm not limiting the use of jQuery just to this answer Max, it can bring efficiencies in the long run in writing code by reducing verbosity and is good practice to learn as an effective UI building tool.